# I am not getting any interface to add values in attribute properties of while adding new attribute

Tags: magento2.2.2

When adding new attribute to the product and select the option 'multiple select' for the Catalog input type for the store owner. In image, the values section is showing nothing to add new values.
[image: In values section nothing is there to add new values]

Comment: Please explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to run this commands:**

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

chmod -R 777 var pub